# Laravel 8 - unsupported_grant_type

Tags: php, laravel, http, http-post, laravel-8

I have a problem with the following:

- I am creating an API (I'm new with this)
- With this API I want to consume another API or WebService
- In Postman I make a get request to the URL and it returns OK the access_token, but in the Laravel project it returns: `"error" => "unsupported_grant_type".`

This is my code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ])->post('http://url:52904/Token', [
            'userName' => 'menganito',
            'password' => 'pepito',
            'grant_type' => 'password'
        ]);

        dd($response->json());
```

I tried installing ** Laravel Passport **, but I'm not using a DB for now.

Comment: What are the parameters you send in postman and what api is consuming?

Comment: This is more like an [OAuth2 Grant Type](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/) issue than a Laravel issue. Please use Postman to do a POST request with the same `grant_type` and data to see if it return the same result. If so, the API you're using simply does not support that grant type (as the error suggested).

Comment: In postman i send x-www-form-urlencoded but if i choose form-params
return "error" => "unsupported_grant_type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was x-www-form-urlencoded.

This solved my problem (asForm)

```
$response = Http::asForm()->post('http://url.com', [
                'userName' => 'user',
                'password' => 'pass',
                'grant_type' => 'password'
        ]);

dd($response->json());
```